# How to validate arbitrary conditions when authenticating an user?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

Let's say I have an ASP.NET MVC Core application, and I want to validate certain custom conditions when allowing authentication. For example, an user that provides a valid pair of credentials, but is disabled by the application's administrator, or a flag that indicates the user is up-to-date with his payments, or any other arbitrary condition. Is there a place in ASP.NET Core Identity where I can hook this custom validation? I have to make this work for local and external authentication.

Comment: Hi, @Léster, please let us know if you have updated information on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For you case, you could create custom user validators.

> Writing a custom validator for ASP.NET Core Identity

**Custom User Validator That Requires E-Mail Addresses to End in @example.com**

This follows a common pattern within Identity, where you can either implement the interface (in this case `IValidator<T>`) and provide all of the validation code, or override the base implementation of it and add additional logic by overriding methods as I did here.

```
public class CustomUserValidator : UserValidator<ApplicationUser>
{
  public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, 
    ApplicationUser user)
  {
    IdentityResult baseResult = await base.ValidateAsync(manager, user);
    List<IdentityError> errors = new List<IdentityError>(baseResult.Errors);

    if (!user.Email.EndsWith("@example.com"))
    {
      IdentityError invalidEmailError = Describer.InvalidEmail(user.Email);
      invalidEmailError.Description += " Email address must end with @example.com";
      errors.Add(invalidEmailError);
    }

    return errors.Count > 0 ? IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray()) : IdentityResult.Success;
  }
}
```

Then to plug this in, head over to the Startup.cs file and find the `ConfigureServices` method. Somewhere before the line starting with `services.AddIdentity`, add the following line:

```
services.AddTransient<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserValidator>();
```

This will add the implementation of `CustomUserValidator` to the internal services collection, allowing it to be injected anywhere that an `IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>` is required.